# How to use groupBy in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, group-by

I have this model class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    string Barcode { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

How can I group a list of `Transaction` items, and return a new list

```
["barcode1"[list Transaction1], "barcode2"[list Transaction2],...]
```

Thank very much

I only know `groupBy(x=>x.Key)`, it will return `[[list Transction1],[list Transction1]]`, I need key Barcode in each list

Comment: Add `.Select(record => record.barcode)`

Answer (score 2):

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<Transaction>> groupedTransactions = transactions
    .GroupBy(t => t.Barcode)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

This code would work. You are using both GroupBy, and then throwing it all together in a dictionary.

Comment: I tried and success, thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find `.ToLookup()` method suitable. It transforms a list into a kind of 'dictionary', only with multiple values for each key.

```
var lookup = transactionList.ToLookup(t=>t.Barcode);
// usage
foreach(var tran in lookup["barcode1"])
{ ... }
```